# Apply one autocomplete to different input fields in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I want to apply autocomplete source to several different input fields on the same page. I do the same thing for inputs but autocomplete work for first input and for others do not. These are my inputs:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
<br>
<label>Search 1: <label>
<input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" name="country" size="60" 
 id="autocomplete-ajax"> 
</div>
<br>

 <div class="col-sm-10">
 <br>
  <label>Search 2<label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" name="country"  
   size="60" id="autocomplete-ajax"> 
 </div>
```

Autocompletion is done by some libraries. I did not write any code. Libraries are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="suggestion/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="suggestion/scripts/jquery.mockjax.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="suggestion/src/jquery.autocomplete.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="suggestion/scripts/countries.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="suggestion/scripts/demo.js"></script>
```

Now, how can I solve this problem and apply autocomplete to different inputs in one page?

Comment: I'm afraid we're gonna need more code to understand how to help with this issue. We can't see how you are hooking to your HTML, if you are using separate libraries or data sources for the fields, etc.

Comment: Which autocomplete are you using? jQuery UI?

Comment: It was an id in demo.js, when I changed it to class it worked for existing ones. Thanks a lot for your attention.